# How can I create different types from uint32_t that are statically different?

Tags: c++

I want to create different types that are uint32_t but are different from compilers perspective -- they can only be compared and assigned to a value of the exact same type. Here is a sample code that I want to achieve:

```cpp
TextureResourceId t1 = 1000, t2 = 2000;
PipelineResourceId p1 = 1000, p2 = 2000;
BufferResourceId b1 = 1000, b2 = 1000;

if (t1 == t2) // OK!
if (t1 == p1) // Compiler error!
if (t1 == b1) // Compiler error!
```

I know that I can do some preprocessor magic to achieve this:

```cpp
#define CREATE_RESOURCE_ID(NAME) \
    class NAME { \
    public: \
        NAME(uint32_t value_): value(value_) {} \
        bool operator==(const NAME &rhs) { return value == rhs.value; } \
    private: \
        uint32_t value; \
    };

CREATE_RESOURCE_ID(TextureResourceId);
CREATE_RESOURCE_ID(BufferResourceId);
CREATE_RESOURCE_ID(PipelineResourceId);

int main() {
    TextureResourceId tex1(1000), tex2(2000);
    BufferResourceId buf1(1000);
    PipelineResourceId pip1(1000);


    if (tex1 == tex2) {}
    if (buf1 == tex1) {}
    if (tex1 == pip1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

But I would like to know if there is a more C++'y way of doing this (e.g with inheritance or some kind of syntax with enum classes)

Comment: maybe boost strong typedef

Comment: Consider having a template `ressource_id` class to which you can provide some unique tag type. No need for a macro for this.

Comment: One of Ada's features.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do maths with them? Another possibility is `enum class my_type: std::size_t {};` and use casting to set and retrieve values.

Comment: Since C++11. use `uint32_t` as a base for a set of `enum` types - although that limits use of the type in numerical operations.    You can also wrap the `uint32_t` in different class types, but that will mean a need to overload operators for each class type  (Your macro approach implements a simple form of the latter).

Comment: @Peter I suppose you could do most operations because there is an implicit conversion enum -> integer. Maybe Gasim's needs are met by the fact that integer -> enum as well as enum1 -> enum2 are only possible with explicit conversions.

Comment: Replace the macro with a CRTP. `template <class Derived> struct ResourceId { ... };` Then use `struct TextureResourceId : ResourceId<TextureResourceId> {};`.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica - It depends on what set of operations the OP intends to perform.    Some operations can by used due to implicit conversions.   Some require use of explicit conversions.    That mix of "some things can be done, others require more explicit effort by programmer" is what I was alluding to with the wording "limits use".

Comment: Thank you everyone, I went with the `enum class` approach as that provided the cleanest approach for my use-case, which only requires assigning and checking if the two values match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only seem to need to check identity, an `enum` should be the natural choice and as you mention, `enum class` can be used to ensure the underlying type is `uint32_t`:

```
enum class TextureResourceId: uint32_t
{
    id1 = 1000,
    id2 = 2000
};

enum class PipelineResource: uint32_t
{
    id1 = 1000,
    id2 = 2000
};

enum class BufferResourceId: uint32_t
{
    id1 = 1000,
    id2 = 2000
};
```

With values initialized as in the example:

```
TextureResourceId t1 = TextureResourceId::id1, t2 = TextureResourceId::id2;
PipelineResourceId p1 = PipelineResourceId::id1, p2 = PipelineResourceId::id2;
BufferResourceId b1 = BufferResourceId::id1, b2 = BufferResourceId::id2;
```

The compiler should behave as specified, i.e. allow IDs to be compared within the same class, but not across different classes.

Note: if you do not want to explicitly declare all possible identities in the enum classes, identities can also be constructed from integers, e.g. `TextureResourceId(1000)`.

Comment: The original solution can define IDs are runtime. This solution only allows for compile-time ID definitions.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you for mentioning this. However, as I was just adding in a note, it is also possible to construct instances from integers which can be used to define IDs during runtime.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I didn't know that you can have an empty enum class and set values values in runtime, which is perfect for my use-case.

Comment: @Gasim Be careful, because it is an unexpected use of enums and may confuse other developers. A lot of people think this is not allowed. If your code needs to pass any kind of review, this solution will probably be rejected. I do not recommend this solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why is this an unexpected use of enums? Empty enums are the canonical way, I think, since this is exactly how the [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) type is defined by the C++17 standard, for example.

Comment: @heapunderrun Because it is not an enumeration. Most developers still think it would be Undefined or Unspecified behavior if you asked them. Whether it is allowed or not, it is bound to confuse a large portion of developers. It is the same as using tricky expressions for brevity when a more verbose equivalent.

Comment: @heapunderrun [continued] I don't think they would have made `std::byte` an enum class if they had any other choice, but to make it a `class` would have put an extra burden on implementers due to its use as a type specifically used for memory operations. For example `struct byte { unsigned char; };` isn't technically required to have `sizeof(byte) == 1` even if it almost certainly always will, but `std::byte` *needs* to have a guaranteed size of 1. There are no such constraints in the context of this question.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This question has specifically the constraint of using `uint32_t` as the underlying type. As to what "many developers think", I am quite sure none of us have a statistically significant sample to say anything certain. I would anytime recommend the simplest/clearest solution (of course under constraints of existing code base and company coding standards). Which solution is best depends so much on context that it is impossible to say anything certain here. We can present options so that OP and others may choose what is useful in their context. [End of meta for me].

Comment: @nielsen Well, I would confidently disagree about sample size. I would also disagree that this question's constraint is similar to those of `std::byte`, nothing in the question suggests the other answer would not work in this case (which wouldn't work for `std::byte`). And I agree that this solution can be simple and clean and that different answers can present different options for OP to choose from. My criticism of the solution isn't asking you to delete the answer, it's expressing concerns about the consequences so the OP can be better informed.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a templated archetype and make type-tagged versions of that.

I made this a while back and haven't used it yet, so no testing, but I think the idea should be sound:

```
template<typename Type, typename Number>
class typed_id
{
public:
    explicit typed_id(Number n): n(n) {}
    typed_id(typed_id const& id): n(id.n) {}

    typed_id& operator=(typed_id const& n) { this->n  = n.n; return *this; }

    bool operator<(typed_id id) const { return this->n < id.n; }
    bool operator>(typed_id id) const { return this->n > id.n; }

    bool operator==(typed_id id) const { return this->n == id.n; }
    bool operator!=(typed_id id) const { return this->n != id.n; }

private:
    Number n;
};

// tag types to differentiate each
// instantiation of the archetype
struct TextureResourceIdTag{};
struct PipelineResourceIdTag{};
struct BufferResourceIdTag{};

// actual types    
using TextureResourceId = typed_id<TextureResourceIdTag, std::size_t>;
using PipelineResourceId = typed_id<PipelineResourceIdTag, std::size_t>;
using BufferResourceId = typed_id<BufferResourceIdTag, std::size_t>;

int main()
{
    TextureResourceId t1{1000};
    TextureResourceId t2{2000};
    PipelineResourceId p1{1000};
    PipelineResourceId p2{2000};
    BufferResourceId b1{1000};
    BufferResourceId b2{2000};

    if (t1 == t2) {} // OK!
    if (t1 == p1) {} // Compiler error!
    if (t1 == b1) {} // Compiler error!
}
```

Comment: `Number operator()() const { return n; }` is also possible, does that add any value?

Comment: @Passerby Did you mean `operator Number() const { return n; }` (casting)? If so, it may do, depending on what you want to use this for. Obviously when you add flexibility, you reduce encapsulation/safety.

Comment: Enum class was perfect for my use-case but I am going to keep this one in mind if I see that I need to more functionality than assignment and equality checking. Thank you for this answer!